# Linq to NHibernate return entities whose name starts with contents of string list

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, collections, linq-to-nhibernate

Is it possible to do something like this in Linq to NHibernate - "Get all entities whose name starts with any string from the list".

I have this query:

```
var result=session.Query<Entity>()
                  .Where(e=> listOfStrings.Any(s=> e.Name.StartsWith(s)))
                  .ToList();
```

but I get

> "NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported."

Comment: Does the list come from the database too? In that case i can provide an example using Detached Criteria...

Comment: Which version of nhibernate you are using ?

Comment: No. The list of strings is from the application (user input). 
I use NHibernate.3.3.3.4001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Entity>();
var disjunction = new Disjunction();

foreach (var s in listOfStrings)
{
    disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Entity>(e => e.Name)
        .IsLike(s, MatchMode.Start));
}

var result = query.Where(disjunction).List();
```